# Access StringVar() as a normal string in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to access value of selected Radiobutton and compare it with if statement but on accessing the value I am getting PY_VAR0 instead.

```
from tkinter import *
ComplaintForm=Tk()
typesel=StringVar()#<--variable I'm using to access value of selected Radiobutton
HighVoltage=Radiobutton(ComplaintForm,text='High Voltage Motor',value='HighVoltage',\
                      anchor=W,font='roboto 18',bg='white',variable=typesel)
HighVoltage.grid(row=5,column=1,padx=5,pady=10)

LowVoltage=Radiobutton(ComplaintForm,text='Low Voltage Motor',value='LowVoltage',\
                      anchor=W,font='roboto 18',bg='white',variable=typesel)
LowVoltage.grid(row=5,column=0,padx=5,pady=10)

print(typesel)#this is printing PY_VAR0 instead of accessing value of above Radiobuttons
mainloop()
```

PS: I know there are some malpractices in this code which have been introduced to keep the code minimal and problem easily understandable.

Comment: If you search for `[tkinter] py_var0` on this site you will find many questions and answers that would probably tell you what you need.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can access the value of a tkinter Variable Class `BooleanVar`, `DoubleVar`, `IntVar`, or `StringVar` like this:

```
my_variable = tk.StringVar()
my_variable.set('value')
print(my_variable.get())   # <-- returns and prints the value contained in my_variable
```

see [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) for more info.