# write() argument must be str not stringvar

Tags: python, tkinter

I don't know what can I do, so I'm asking for help. When I click that "submitting_button" error occur "write() argument must be str not stringvar"

```
import tkinter as tk

from tkinter import ttk, Label, Button, Entry, Place, Pack, StringVar

class Datasaver:
    def __init__(self, GUI,):
        self.GUI = GUI
        GUI.title("Dataver")

        self.label = Label(GUI, text="More comfortable method for saving data!",font=("Arial", 20))
        self.label.place(relx = 0.1, rely = 0.5, anchor = 'sw')
        self.submitting_button = Button(GUI, text="submit", command=self.submitting_button)
        self.submitting_button.place(relx = 0.9, rely = 0.9, anchor = 'sw')
        self.close_button = Button(GUI, text="Exit", command=GUI.quit)
        self.close_button.place(relx = 0.9, rely = 1.0, anchor = 'sw')
        self.butt = Button(GUI, text="create", command=self.create)
        self.butt.place(relx = 0.9, rely = 0.8, anchor = 'sw')
        self.labelel = Label(GUI, text="Username:")
        self.labelel.place(relx = 0.0, rely = 0.8, anchor = 'sw')
        self.labelel = Label(GUI, text="Password:")
        self.labelel.place(relx = 0.0, rely = 0.9, anchor = 'sw')
        self.labelel = Label(GUI, text="E-mail:")
        self.labelel.place(relx = 0.0, rely = 1.0, anchor = 'sw')
        self.entry = Entry(GUI, textvariable = name_variable, show="*", font=("Arial", 10))
        self.entry.place(relx = 0.2, rely = 0.9, anchor = 'sw')
        self.entry2 = Entry(GUI, textvariable = password_var, font=("Arial", 10))
        self.entry2.place(relx = 0.2, rely = 1.0, anchor='sw')
        self.entry3 = Entry(GUI, textvariable = Email_var, font=("Arial", 10))
        self.entry3.place(relx = 0.2, rely = 0.8, anchor='sw')

    def create(self):
        f = open("myfile.txt", "x")
        
    def submitting_button(self):
        file = open("myfile.txt", "w", encoding="utf8")
        file.write(name_variable)
        file.write(password_var)
        file.write(Email_var)
        file.close()
        
        name=name_variable.get()
        password=password_var.get()
        Email=Email_var.get()
        print("Nickname: " + name)
        print("Password: " + password)
        print("Email: " + Email)
        name_variable.set("")
        password_var.set("")
        Email_var.set("")
        
        
root = tk.Tk()
root.resizable(False, False)
root.geometry('600x350') 

name_variable=StringVar()
password_var=StringVar()
Email_var=StringVar()

my_gui = Datasaver(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Format your code correctly please

Comment: That error information has all of the information you need. You are calling a function that requires a string, but you are passing it a stringvar. stringvars are not strings.

Comment: It should be `file.write(name_variable.get())` and similar for the other variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extend on [Barmar's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) answer:

`StringVar` is a Tkinter class that helps manage the values of a widget. As such a `StringVar` object *holds* a string (in it's `value` attribute) but *is not* a string itself.

`file.write()` on the other hand expects a string.

As explained here [Access StringVar() as a normal string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51121144/access-stringvar-as-a-normal-string-in-python) you can get the value of the `StringVar` variable by using the `get()` method.

To make it short, all you need to do is change the following lines:

```
def submitting_button(self):
    # ...
    file.write(name_variable.get())
    file.write(password_var.get())
    file.write(Email_var.get())
    # ...
```